# Проверка уникальности localstorage и обновление

Tags: javascript

Сохраняю в localstorage массив:

```
var myLikes = [];
myLikes[0] = {'slide':slide_id}
localStorage.setItem("myCollection", JSON.stringify(myLikes));
```

Далее мне нужно проверить является ли новое значение уникальным и если нет - добавить его в массив myCollection. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
var slide_id = $$('#likes').attr('slide_id');

var arrayLikes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCollection')); 

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLikes.length; i++) {

    if (slide_id == arrayLikes[i].slide) { // dublicate

      console.log('Dublicate');

    } else {

      console.log('New' + arrayLikes[i].slide);

      arrayLikes.push({'slide':slide_id});

      localStorage.setItem("myCollection", JSON.stringify(arrayLikes));

    }

}
```

В итоге проверка не работает и в localstorage добавляются все значения, в том числе дубликаты + массив начинает увеличиваться в геометрической прогрессии.

Что я делаю не так и как мне правильно выполнить проверку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var slide_id = $('#likes').attr('slide_id');
var arrayLikes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCollection'));
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLikes.length; i++) {
  if (slide_id == arrayLikes[i].slide) { // dublicate
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (found) {
  console.log('Dublicate');
} else {
  console.log('New' + arrayLikes[i].slide);
  arrayLikes.push({
    'slide': slide_id
  });
  localStorage.setItem("myCollection", JSON.stringify(arrayLikes));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Объектный подход весьма сильно упростил бы эту задачу.
Например, можно унаследовать от `Array`:

```
class MyLikes extends Array {
  constructor(storageKey) {
    super(); 
    Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey) || '[]')); 
  }
  findLikeIdx(likeObj) { return this.findIndex(o => o.slide == likeObj.slide); }
  addLike(likeObj) {
    const idx = this.findLikeIdx(likeObj); 
    return (idx >= 0) ? idx : this.push(likeObj) - 1;
  }
  store(storageKey) { localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(this)); }
}

const stKey = 'myCollection', 
const likes = new MyLikes(stKey);     // создание экземпляра объекта и чтение данных из localStorage
/* ... */
likes.addLike({ slide: slide_id });   // добавление без дубликатов
/* ... */
likes.store(stKey);                   // запись в localStorage
```

[<kbd>`Демо в JSbin   ‎`</kbd>](https://jsbin.com/kugizififi/edit?html,js,output)